# Python Suds - Confusion About Adding Item to Array

Tags: python, suds

I'm trying to generate a soap request with suds that has an array of items in it. I can't get the array inserted properly, everything I try is just setting the array container to the array item instead.

I've tried setting and appending to the same result.

Python code

```
add_request = client.factory.create('AddRequest')

add_request_identity = client.factory.create('Identity')
add_request_identity.NameTypeCode = '06'
add_request_identity.ApplicationIdentityIdentifier = 'true'
add_request_identity.FamilyName = 'Fname98765432000'
add_request_identity.GivenNames = 'Gname98765432000'
add_request_identity.Gender = '01'
add_request_identity.DateOfBirth = '1990-06-27'
add_request_identity.DateOfBirthType = 'ACTUAL'
add_request_identity.PlaceOfBirth = 'OTTAWA'
add_request_identity.CountryOfBirth = 'CAN'

add_request.Identity = [add_request_identity]
```

I have also tried

```
add_request.Identity = add_request_identity

add_request.Identity.append(add_request_identity) 
(this throws an error "suds AttributeError: 'ArrayOfIdentity' object has no attribute 'append'")

add_request.Identity = []
add_request.Identity.append(add_request_identity) 

add_request_identity_array = client.factory.create('ArrayOfIdentity')
add_request_identity_array = [add_request_identity]
add_request.Identity = add_request_identity_array
```

But they all result in the same output

Actual output

```
<ns0:Add>
         <ns0:Request>
             <ns0:Identity>
               <ns0:NameTypeCode>06</ns0:NameTypeCode>
  <ns0:ApplicationIdentityIdentifier>true</ns0:ApplicationIdentityIdentifier>
               <ns0:FamilyName>Fname98765432000</ns0:FamilyName>
               <ns0:GivenNames>Gname98765432000</ns0:GivenNames>
               <ns0:Gender>01</ns0:Gender>
               <ns0:DateOfBirth>1990-06-27</ns0:DateOfBirth>
               <ns0:DateOfBirthType>ACTUAL</ns0:DateOfBirthType>
               <ns0:PlaceOfBirth>OTTAWA</ns0:PlaceOfBirth>
               <ns0:CountryOfBirth>CAN</ns0:CountryOfBirth>
            </ns0:Identity>
```

What I'm trying to get (this is what is generated with SoapUI)

```
<v1:Add>
         <v1:Request>
            <v1:Identity>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <v1:Identity>
                  <v1:NameTypeCode>06</v1:NameTypeCode>
                  <v1:ApplicationIdentityIdentifier>true</v1:ApplicationIdentityIdentifier>
                  <v1:FamilyName>Fname234567022</v1:FamilyName>
                  <v1:GivenNames>Gname234567022</v1:GivenNames>
                  <v1:Gender>01</v1:Gender>
                  <v1:DateOfBirth>1990-06-27</v1:DateOfBirth>
                  <v1:DateOfBirthType>ACTUAL</v1:DateOfBirthType>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v1:PlaceOfBirth>OTTAWA</v1:PlaceOfBirth>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <v1:CountryOfBirth>CAN</v1:CountryOfBirth>
               </v1:Identity>
            </v1:Identity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my own. The top Identity element had a child Identity element.

```
add_request_identity_array = client.factory.create('ArrayOfIdentity')
add_request_identity_array.Identity = [add_request_identity1, add_request_identity2]
add_request.Identity = add_request_identity_array
```

OR

```
add_request.Identity.Identity = [add_request_identity1, add_request_identity2]
```